# Inserting and Deleting node at given position of a Linked List in Python

Tags: python, linked-list, nodes

I'm using a Linked List to store a collection consisting of the 3 attributes `id`, `bookName`, and `authorName` as the parameter to add a book. The objects are defined in the "Book" class.

The code will work like a shelf in the library, storing 3 types of information, `id`, `BookName` and `AuthorName` into the Linked List node in the "Book" class.

I am now working on 3 methods in the `LinkedList` class which are incomplete.

They are:

**AddBookToPosition (newBook, n)**  - Will add the Book to the desired position 'n' (for example 2)
**DeleteBookAtPosition (n)** - Will delete the Book to the desired position 'n' (for example 3)
**SortByAuthorName()** - Will sort the author names stored in the linked list in ascending order.

**Problem:**
There are no errors when compiling, however **AddBookAtPosition** is not working and does not display the Book added in the Output. Also **DeleteBookAtPosition** would not work as well.

I need help (for AddBookAtPosition) and delete (DeleteBookAtPosition) which will add or delete the node at position n of the linked list respectively, say that the program displays the book in order from position 0,1,2, so forth.

Appreciate the advice.

```
class Node :
    def __init__(self, data=None, next=None):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None

class Book :
    def __init__(self,n,id,bookName,authorName):
        self.n = n
        self.id = id
        self.bookName = bookName
        self.authorName = authorName

    def print(self):
        print("Position: {}".format(self.n))
        print("Book ID: {}".format(self.id))
        print("Book Name: {}".format(self.bookName))
        print("Author Name: {}".format(self.authorName))


class LinkedList :
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

    def __iter__(self):
        node = self.head
        while node is not None:
            yield node
            node = node.next

    def __len__(self):
       return len(list(self))

    def __getitem__(self, i):
        node = self.head
        if node is None:
            raise IndexError('LinkedList index out of range')
        for n in range(i-1):
            node = node.next
            if node is None:
                raise IndexError('LinkedList index out of range')
            return node

    #this will add the book to the top of the list
    def AddBookToFront (self, newBook):
        new_node = Node(newBook)
        new_node.next = self.head
        self.head = new_node

    def AddBookAtPosition (self, newBook, n):
        counter = 1
        if n == 0:
            newBook.setNext(self.head)
            self.head = newBook

        else:
            node = self.head
            while node.next is not None :
                if counter == n :
                    newBook.setNext(node.next)
                    node.setNext(newBook)
                    return
                node = node.next
                counter = counter + 1    

    def DeleteBookAtPosition(self, n):

        # If linked list is empty
        if self.head == None:
            return

        # Store head node
        temp = self.head

        # If head needs to be removed
        if n == 0:
            self.head = temp.next
            temp = None
            return

        # Find previous node of the node to be deleted
        for i in range(n -1 ):
            temp = temp.next
            if temp is None:
                break

        # If position is more than number of nodes
        if temp is None:
            return
        if temp.next is None:
            return

        # Node temp.next is the node to be deleted
        # store pointer to the next of node to be deleted
        next = temp.next.next

        # Unlink the node from linked list
        temp.next = None
        temp.next = next





    def __delitem__(self, i):
        if self.head is None:
            raise IndexError('LinkedList index out of range')
        if i == 0:
            self.head = self.head.next
        else:
            node = self.head
            for n in range(i-1):
                if node.next is None:
                    raise IndexError('LinkedList index out of range')
                node = node.next
            if node.next is None:
                raise IndexError('LinkedList index out of range')
            node.next = node.next.next



BookList = LinkedList()
BookList.AddBookToFront(Book(1, "J.R.R. Tolkien", "Lord of the Rings"))
BookList.AddBookToFront(Book(2, "Lewis Carroll", "Alice in Wonderland"))
BookList.AddBookAtPosition(Book(3, "Star Wars: Aftermath", "Chuck Wendig"), 3)

for book in BookList:
    print(book.data.n)
    print(book.data.id)
    print(book.data.bookName)
    print(book.data.authorName)
```

**Current output**

```
2
Lewis Carroll
Alice in Wonderland
1
J.R.R. Tolkien
Lord of the Rings
```

**Desired output** - to be displayed by position in ascending order (1,2,3)

```
Position : 1
Book ID : 3
Book Name: Star Wars: Aftermath
Author Name: Chuck Wendig

Position : 2
Book ID : 1
Book Name: Lord of the Rings
Author Name: J.R.R. Tolkien
```

Comment: why not just make a list of book objects ? you can then add/remove whatever object you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why does book have both self.n and self.id? The book itself shouldn't know anything about its position. Neither linked list node should know about it's position. The main feature of linked list that you require only to modify *one* of existing elements when you insert a new element. You eliminate all it's benefits if you store position in Book/Node because you *have to* update all following elements once you inserting into your linked list.

At first, modify book this way:

```
class Book :
    def __init__(self, id, bookName, authorName):
        self.id = id
        self.bookName = bookName
        self.authorName = authorName
```

You may implement your own LinkedList.iteritems() method which will return node position while you iterate through nodes:

```
def iteritems(self):
    pos = 0
    for book in self:
        yield pos, book
        pos += 1
```

Notice that it will show false values if you modify linked list while iterating it. Usage example:

```
BookList = LinkedList()
# you've mixed up book name and author name 
BookList.AddBookToFront(Book(1, "J.R.R. Tolkien", "Lord of the Rings"))
BookList.AddBookToFront(Book(2, "Lewis Carroll", "Alice in Wonderland"))
BookList.AddBookToFront(Book(3, "Donald Knuth", "C programming language"))
BookList.AddBookAtPosition(Book(4, "Star Wars: Aftermath", "Chuck Wendig"), 1)

for position, book in BookList.iteritems():
    print("Position: %s" % position)
    print("Book ID: %s" % book.data.id)
    print("Book Name: %s" % book.data.bookName)
    print("Author Name: %s" % book.data.authorName)
```

Output:

```
Position: 0
Book ID: 3
Book Name: Donald Knuth
Author name: C programming language
Position: 1
Book ID: 4
Book Name: Star Wars: Aftermath
Author name: Chuck Wendig
Position: 2
Book ID: 2
Book Name: Lewis Carroll
Author name: Alice in Wonderland
Position: 3
Book ID: 1
Book Name: J.R.R. Tolkien
Author name: Lord of the Rings
```

A also fixed "AddBookAtPosition" for you because it didn't worked. It used "new book" instead of "new node":

```
def AddBookAtPosition(self, newBook, n):
    new_node = Node(newBook)
    counter = 1
    if n == 0:
        new_node.next = self.head
        self.head = new_node

    else:
        node = self.head
        while node.next is not None :
            if counter == n :
                new_node.next = node.next
                node.next = new_node
                return
            node = node.next
            counter = counter + 1
```

Comment: Thank you. This helped me understand better. May I also ask, how do I go about Having the list display the books in ascending order by adding a method "SortByBookName"? You can take a look here - https://github.com/darkgenesisx/d1/blob/master/BookCollection.py

Comment: LinkedList-specific sorting algorithms may be tricky to start with. I think you could implement bubble sort. You compare *node.data.bookName* and *node.next.data.bookName* and swap them if required. You do this form first node to last, and again, and again, and stop it when after complete run from first to last node nothing changed (use boolean flag). It's not efficient, but it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

I think a python list would do the work for you. (Unless you specify why you need a LL)

```
class Book :
    def __init__(self,id,bookName,authorName):
        self.id = id
        self.bookName = bookName
        self.authorName = authorName

    def print(self):
        print("Book ID: {}".format(self.id))
        print("Book Name: {}".format(self.bookName))
        print("Author Name: {}".format(self.authorName))


BookList = list()
#to add book object using index
BookList.insert(0,Book(1, "J.R.R. Tolkien", "Lord of the Rings"))
BookList.insert(1,Book(2, "Lewis Carroll", "Alice in Wonderland"))
BookList.insert(2,Book(3, "Star Wars: Aftermath", "Chuck Wendig"))

# to remove object from list using index
del BookList[1]

#print whole list
for book in BookList:
    print(book.id)
    print(book.bookName)
    print(book.authorName)
```